# cgps and gpsmon delivering different values

Tags: gpsd

i am currently getting myself into gpsd and had been playing around with it a little, until i noticed the following issue:

The console commands `gpsmon` and `cgps` are showing different values.
To be exact, the difference between both is around `3'`. The `cgps` value is the correct one, `gpsmon` is `3'` off.

Since this is not a small number, i'd like to find out what could be the problem here.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by "cleaning up" gpsd.

```
sudo systemctl stop gpsd
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyACM0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Then everything  works just fine.

Comment: It worked also for me! Do you know why gpsd was giving wrongs results? Thanks!