# Why would gpspipe always output the same lat/lon, but gpsmon correctly shows variable coordinates?

Tags: gpsd

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an x86 system and I have a USB GPS antenna which shows up as /dev/ttyACM0. If I run "gpspipe -w", I see the same lat/lon coordinates printed over and over. If I physically move the device, the coordinates still never update. (It's like it's stuck with the first set of coordinates it ever sees.) However, if I instead run gpsmon, I see slightly-varying GPS coordinates, as I would expect.

The same antenna on a Raspberry Pi ARM system, running Raspbian, works fine, in the sense that the gpspipe -w output varies slightly between each coordinate output.

I try the "cleaning up" instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758488/cgps-and-gpsmon-delivering-different-values), but after I do that, if I run gpspipe -w again, nothing is output. But restarting the machine brings it back to a semi-working state (with gpsmon working, and gpspipe "not working" in the sense that it only outputs the same coordinates over and over again.)